# delete duplicated column dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This morning while doing some analysis with a data frame I got an error due to the presence of duplicated column names. I tried to find a solution using exclusively dplyr but I could not find anything that works. Here is an example to illustrate the problem. A dataframe with a duplicated column name.

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(c(1, 2, 3),
                c(2,2,1),nrow=2,ncol=3))
colnames(x) <- c("a", "a", "b")
```

When I try to drop the first column using the select command I get an error

```
x %>%
  select(-1)%>%filter(b>1)

Error: found duplicated column name: a
```

I can get rid of the column easily using traditional indexing and the using dplyr to filter by value

```
x<-x[,-1]%>%filter(b>1)
```

Which produces the desired output

```
> x
  a b
1 2 3
2 2 3
```

Any ideas on how to perform this using only dplyr grammar?

Comment: Well in base R, the "right" way is probably `x[!duplicated(names(x), fromLast=TRUE)]`. Just find a way to toss that into dplyr's `select` verb. Huh, even `x %>% select(2,3)` doesn't work, whining about the LHS before looking at the `select` clause. I'd call that a bug. Crude workaround: `x %>% do(.[!duplicated(names(.), fromLast=TRUE)])`

Comment: I usually just use `make.names` to rename everything legally.

Comment: If you dig around I think that you will find the root of evil here lies in the fact that plyr and dplyr use column names to select data. This REQUIRES that columns have unique names, it does not select by name and contents. The base package uses indexes, which will work without regard for naming paradigms. It is a limit of the package, well worth the limit most of the time.

Comment: Yeah I came to that conclusion, the interesting part is that you can not delete columns with the same name but you can actually create columns with the same name, which for consistency sake should also throw an error message.

Answer (score 3):

This could work, taking advantage of `make.names` behaviour. Don't know if I've cheated here, but it seems mostly to take advantage of dplyr functions.

```
x %>% 
    setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
    select(-matches("*\\.[1-9]+$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get rid of the first column completely I would just do

```
x <- x[, c(2:3)]
```

Or alternatively you could rename it

```
colnames(x)[1] <- "a.1"
```